# Uncorrelatedness of $|X_1|^2$ and $|X_2|^2$, if $X_1\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_X^2)$ and $X_2\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_X^2)$ are uncorrelated

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence, correlation

Let $X_1$ and $X_1$ be uncorrelated identically distributed zero-mean complex Gaussian random variables, i.e., $X_1\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_X^2)$ and $X_2\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_X^2)$.

Knowing that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated, what can we say about exponentially distributed random variables $|X_1|^2$ and $|X_2|^2$? Are they uncorrelated, or we lost the uncorrelatedness?

What if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent instead? I believe the independence will be preserved between $|X_1|^2$ and $|X_2|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

In general uncorrelated does not  imply independence.

Your second belief - independence of two R.V. implies independence of functions of the two R.V.  is correct.

Comment: But isn't that true only for Gaussian random variables whose joint distribution is also Gaussian? In general, your first statement is not correct, uncorrelated Gaussian random variables are not necessarily independent.

Comment: @Veljko I was not aware of the statement about uncorrelated Gaussian variables not necessarily independent.  Do you have an example?

Comment: There is one example on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: @Veljko  I stand corrected.  I modified my answer accordingly.